# GET Request works with terminal curl but doesn't work with python request library

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

This curl request works perfectly fine if made from the terminal:

```
curl -kg 'https://website.com/wellview/api/tablename?filter[where][id]=123456' -H "Authorization: Bearer sjfjkdjskdfjlsdflks12313123"
```

But if I try to replicate it with the python request library, I receive a 403, Forbidden, response:

```
s = requests.Session()
path=u'https://website.com/wellview/api/tablename?filter[where][id]=123456'
bearer_token="sjfjkdjskdfjlsdflks12313123"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"}
r= s.get(path, headers = headers, verify = False)
```

I had to mask the real URL and bearer token since they're sensible information.
I get the following response:

```
2023-07-21 17:43:32,267 :: DEBUG :: urllib3.connectionpool :: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): website.com:443
2023-07-21 17:43:32,370 :: DEBUG :: urllib3.connectionpool :: https://website.com:443 "GET /wellview/api/tablename?filter%5Bwhere%5D%5Bid%5D=123456 HTTP/1.1" 403 146
```

I think the problem might reside with the square brackets being percent encoded by the request library, I don't know how to overcome this problem though, any ideas?

I get the same result even if I set the filter as a parameter in the params argument for the request:

```
base_url = "https://website.com/wellview/api/tablename"
bearer_token="sjfjkdjskdfjlsdflks12313123"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"}
params = {'filter[where][id]': '123456'}            
response = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers, params=params,verify=False)
```

[EDIT]
I notice now, the request object shows a comment:

```
2023-07-23 12:58:39,059 :: DEBUG :: charset_normalizer :: Encoding detection: ascii is most likely the one.
```

Comment: Can you try to add `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0'` to the `headers` ?

Comment: I tried adding the User-Agent you suggested, I also tried other agents I found on the internet, the result doesn't change.